# Question regarding the proof of Levelt´s theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

I have a question, regarding the proof of **theorem 3.5 (Levelt)** from the following [article](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Edrinfeld/Hypergeometric_motives/Beukers-Heckman.pdf) about the monodromy of hypergeometric functions. My question is the following:

**In the theorem it is stated, that any hypergeometric group with the same parameters is conjugated in $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ to the initial one. This is, what i dont immediately understand.**

In the proof the author wants to show the uniqueness of the matrices $A$, $B$. He does this by considering $W = ker(B-A)$ which is $n-1$ dimensional and $V=W \cap A^{-1}W \cap ... \cap A^{-(n-2)}W$. He proves for $v \in V$ that $A^i v$ $(i=0,...,n-1)$ is a basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $A^iv = B^iv$ on $W$ for all $i=0,...,n-1$. But how does one see, that the matrices $A$, $B$ have said form as in the theorem with respect to this basis, the uniqueness of $H=<A,B>$ and that all those groups with the same parameters are conjugated to $H$?